# I want re-add the animate-bounce class whenever the itemCount increases it's value

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, jsx, pwa-studio

I want to add class again and again on click handleClick in minicart I got two separate components one component contain the handleClick and other component is the minicart.

Is there any way I can do this?
I am trying this code on handleClick but this doesn't work

```js
useEffect(() => {
    document.querySelector("#minicart-id").classList.add('animate-bounce');
});
```

If I try this without useEffect it works but it only add class one time.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to play the animation again and again, you have to add and remove the className from the span.

First store the classNames inside a state.
Second you have to add the `animate-bounce` class when you increase the cart items.
Third you need a `useEffect` where you remove the `animate-bounce` class after the animation time, for example:

```
const [classNames, setClassNames] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
  let timer;
  if (classNames === "animate-bounce") {
    timer = setTimeout(() => {
      setClassNames();
    }, 1000);
  }

  return () => clearTimeout(timer);
}, [classNames]);
```

Comment: Thanks for help but I am not able to implement this will you please tell me more how I can implement on the JSX like I show above in the question for span and I also tell the which const is increasing so I want to  re-add the class for the bounce animation or do you have any other suggestion you can share

Comment: Just create a handleIncrease function for the add cart button onClick event and when you increase the number of the added items, set the new classname as well: `setClassNames("animate-bounce")`, and don't forget to use the state: `<span className={classNames}>...</span>`